# Laravel Excel plugin ideas

Tags: excel, laravel

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an existing Spreadsheet, which is used as a report.
I have the report data in laravel, but I would like to export that data into the correct fields within the excel template.

For example I would like variable 1 to be located in B7, variable 2 to be located in B8.

Does anyone have any idea on a package for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this package and see. It will helpful for export [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

Comment: Hey are you check my answer? is it ok?